# A* search algorithm in Clojure

Tags: algorithm, matrix, clojure, pathfinding

Cost of nodes are represented by a matrix (called `world`), heuristic cost estimate/g score/f score are all represented in matrices.

The world and its size are stored in global dynamic variables. It looks like this:

> ```
> 1    1    1    1    1
> 1999 1999 1999 1999 1
> 1    1    1    1    1
> 1    1999 1999 1999 1999
> 1    1    1    1    1
> ```

So the shortest path should be in a shape like the number 2.

```
(ns typedclj.rhizome
  (:require [flatland.ordered.set :as fos]))

(use 'clojure.pprint)
(defmacro epprint [expr]
  `(do (pprint '~expr)
       (pprint ~expr)))
(defmacro epprints [& exprs]
  (list* 'do (map (fn [x] (list 'epprint x))
                  exprs)))

(epprints (inc 1) (inc 2))

(def world [[1 1 1 1 1]
            [1999 1999 1999 1999 1]
            [1 1 1 1 1]
            [1 1999 1999 1999 1999]
            [1 1 1 1 1]])

(def ^:dynamic *world-size* 5)
(def ^:dynamic *step-cost* 100)
;(alter-var-root #'*world-size* (constantly 5))

(defn neighbors
  ([yx]
   (neighbors [[-1 0] [1 0] [0 -1] [0 1]] *world-size* yx))
  ([deltas *world-size* yx]
   (filter (fn [new-yx] (every? #(< -1 % *world-size*)
                                new-yx))
           (map #(vec (map + yx %)) deltas))))

(defn heuristic-cost-estimate [[y x]]
  (* *step-cost*
     (- (+ *world-size* *world-size*) y x 2)))

(defn mapmat [f mat]
  (mapv (fn [row]
          (mapv f row))
        mat))
(defn mapmats [f & mats]
  (apply mapv (fn [& rows]
                (apply mapv f rows))
         mats))
(defn randmat []
  (repeatedly *world-size*
              (fn [] (repeatedly
                       *world-size*
                       #(rand-int 10)))))

(defn min-by [f coll]
  (when (seq coll)
    (reduce (fn [min this]
              (if (> (f min) (f this)) this min))
            coll)))

(pprint (randmat))
(let [m1 (randmat)
      m2 (randmat)
      m3 (randmat)]
  (epprints m1 m2 m3)
  (mapmats + m1 m2 m3))

(defn constant-matrix [c]
  (vec (repeat *world-size*
               (vec (repeat *world-size* c)))))

(defn construct-path
  [came-from]
  (loop [path [[4 4]]]
    (let [t (peek path)]
      (if (= t [0 0])
        path
        (recur (conj path (get-in came-from t)))))))

(def astart []
  (let [coords (for [i (range *world-size*)]
                      (for [j (range *world-size*)]
                        [i j]))
             h-score (mapmat heuristic-cost-estimate coords)
             start [0 0]
             goal-y (dec *world-size*)
             goal-x goal-y
             goal [goal-x goal-y]]
         (loop [closedset (fos/ordered-set)
                openset (fos/ordered-set [0 0])
                came-from (constant-matrix [nil nil])
                g-score (assoc-in (constant-matrix 1e8) start 0)
                f-score (mapmats + g-score h-score)
                ]
           (let [
                 current (min-by #(get-in f-score %) openset)
                 openset (disj openset current)
                 closedset (conj closedset current)
                 nbrs (filter (complement closedset)
                              (neighbors current))
                 openset (union openset (set nbrs))
                 ]
             (if (= current goal)
               (construct-path came-from)
               (if (empty? openset)
                 false
                 (let [[came-from g-score f-score]
                       (reduce (fn [[cf gs fs :as to-be-updated] nbr]
                                 (let [current-g-score (get-in g-score current)
                                       nbr-g-score (get-in g-score nbr)
                                       nbr-cost (get-in world nbr)
                                       tentative-g-score (+ current-g-score
                                                            nbr-cost)]
                                   (if (>= tentative-g-score nbr-g-score)
                                     to-be-updated
                                     [(assoc-in cf nbr current)
                                      (assoc-in gs nbr tentative-g-score)
                                      (assoc-in fs nbr (+ tentative-g-score
                                                          (get-in h-score nbr)))])))
                               [came-from g-score f-score]
                               nbrs)]
                   (epprints nbrs
                             current
                             goal
                             closedset
                             openset
                             came-from
                             g-score
                             f-score)
                   (recur closedset openset came-from g-score f-score))))))))
```

Any suggestion for improvement is welcome.